# Ruby: Parse API Response

Tags: ruby, amazon-ec2, hosts

I am trying to geht this script to run: http://dysinger.net/2008/10/13/using-amazon-ec2-metadata-as-a-simple-dns but dosnt work because it is using an old amazon sdk version, i rewrote it to use the new one:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require "rubygems"
require "aws-sdk"

%w(optparse rubygems aws-sdk resolv pp).each {|l| require l}
options = {}
parser = OptionParser.new do |p|
  p.banner = "Usage: hosts [options]"
  p.on("-a", "--access-key USER", "The user's AWS access key ID.") do |aki|
    options[:access_key_id] = aki
  end
  p.on("-s",
       "--secret-key PASSWORD",
       "The user's AWS secret access key.") do |sak|
    options[:secret_access_key] = sak
  end
  p.on_tail("-h", "--help", "Show this message") {
    puts(p)
    exit
  }
  p.parse!(ARGV) rescue puts(p)
end
if options.key?(:access_key_id) and options.key?(:secret_access_key)
  puts "127.0.0.1 localhost"
   AWS.config(options)
    AWS::EC2.new(options)
    answer = AWS::EC2::Client.new.describe_instances
    answer.reservationSet.item.each do |r|
    r.instancesSet.item.each do |i|
      if i.instanceState.name =~ /running/
        puts(Resolv::DNS.new.getaddress(i.privateDnsName).to_s +
             " #{i.keyName}.ec2 #{i.keyName}")
      end
    end
  end
else
  puts(parser)
  exit(1)
end
```

What this should do is outputing a new /etc/hosts file with my ec2 instances in it.

And i get a response =D, but answer is a hash and therefore i get the

```
error undefined method `reservationSet' for #<Hash:0x7f7573b27880>.
```

And this is my problem, since i dont know Ruby at all ( All I was doing was reading Amazon Documentation and playing around so i get an answer ). Somehow in the original example this seemed to work. I suppose that back then, the API did not return a hash, anyway...how can i iterate through a hash like above, to get this to work?

Comment: I would debug the `answer` you get back. It is a hash, so maybe just try `answer.each do |key, value|` on it instead of calling the nonexistent `answer.reservationSet`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code may help you:

```
answer = AWS::EC2::Client.new.describe_instances
reservations = answer[:reservation_set]
reservations.each do |reservation|
  instances = reservation[:instances_set]
  instances.each do |instance|
    if instance[:instance_state][:name] == "running"
      private_dns_name = instance[:private_dns_name]
      key_name = instance[:key_name]
      address = Resolv::DNS.new.getaddress(private_dns_name)
      puts "{address} #{key_name}.ec2 #{key_name}"
    end
  end
end
```

Generally change your code from using methods with names e.g. `item.fooBarBaz` to using a hash e.g. `item[:foo_bar_baz]`

When you're learning Ruby the "pp" command is very useful for pretty-printing variables as you go, such as:

```
pp reservations

pp instances

pp private_dns_name
```